# axis lines=middle and axis lines=center

Tags: pgfplots

Is there a difference between

```
axis lines=middle
```

and

```
axis lines=center
```

options in `pgfplots`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no difference.

From the manual:

> The case `center` is a synonym for `middle`